# Searching for existence within 100 million+ strings 5000 times efficiently

Tags: mysql, search, optimization

I have a text file containing 121 million string, I want to perform 5000 search for existence (i.e. if a given string exists in this text file or not) and I want to finish these 5000 checks in 2 seconds or less.

I thought of different ways to do this, I tried to put all these strings from the text file into a SQL table with a primary index on the string column and perform this query 5000 times:

```
select * from table where string=given_string
```

then check if the result exists or not, but this way led to very long execution time for the whole 5000 query, it was between 20 and 30 seconds.

I wonder if there is an efficient way for me to index/handle this data and search among it 5000 times in an efficient way.

Comment: Sure, build a parallel farm like most everyone

Comment: Details are needed: number of disting words, distribution of the word lengths, distribution of the string lenghts, exact strings or substrings... If you are looking for exact strings, a single hash table with whole strings for keys should be suitable.

Comment: Are the search strings supposed to match whole lines from the text file?  That is no 'substring' or 'partition' matches?

Answer (score 0):

you could add another (temporary) table (even in memory) and bulk insert the 5000 search values in there. Afterwards create a query that joins this table to your big one.

This way you only have 2 queries instead of 5000.

Maybe this speeds up things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your data.

If searched strings are mostly **in** the set, data sorting and using [prefix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structures will help a lot

If searched strings are mostly **not in** the set: You could try to use something like [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TheStrings (
    s VARCHAR(..) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(s)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then use LOAD DATA to populate it.  For searching

```
SELECT s FROM TheStrings
    WHERE s IN ('one', 'two', 'lots', 'more' ...);
```

The first time you run it, it will be slow because of the I/O.  (20-30 seconds seems likely for spinning disks.)  The second time will be what to measure; I expect it to be less than a second.

With SSDs, even the first query would probably be under your 2-second goal.

You said `SELECT *` -- are there other columns?  That might impact the answer; please provide details.

Comment: as far as i remember large sets of data for the IN clause are rather problematic performance wise... See [http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/28/why-large-in-clauses-are-problematic/] for some details on this...  thats why i offered the approach with a second table and joining the two...

Comment: Yes, I have seen trouble with 70K items in an `IN`.  However, 500 may be OK, and possibly faster than shipping a list of 500 rows to insert into your extra table.

Comment: Baron's blog is a decade old, and has some things that are out of date.  In fact the first comment points out that IN is not like OR.  (But then it fails to point out that newer versions turn OR into IN where possible!)  _Static blogs should be outlawed._

Comment: The "1ms" was probably the Query cache kicking in; so bogus.  `ANALYZE` was probably against MyISAM; the OP is hopefully using InnoDB.  Etc, etc.